# python and sql on raspberry 3: i wasn't able to write a value in db using a variable

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi3

i create a table using phpmyadmin and i try to populate it using this:

```
   #!usr/bin/python
   import MySQLdb
   import time

   db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","admin","ObjectRecords")
   curs=db.cursor()

   while True:
       try:
         curs.execute(""" INSERT INTO Records values(i,
                                 CURRENT_DATE(),NOW(),'test')""")
         db.commit()
       except:
         db.rollback()

      print"..........................................."

      time.sleep(5)
```

in curs.execute, **i** is an integer and i want to write its values in the first field of my table. But in this way the table is not populated.
If i use an integer and not i 
curs.execute(""" INSERT INTO Records values(24,
                                     CURRENT_DATE(),NOW(),'test')""")
the table is populated: the first field is always 24, and in fields date and time i can see changes. So anyone could explain how can i pass a value to this field using a variable?
Thanks in advance to anyone can help me

Comment: Why did you tag your question with PHP?

Comment: Sorry. my mistake . edited

Comment: Not world-shaking. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT query syntax is wrong. For example:

```
curs.execute("""INSERT INTO todo (item,priority) values('my_item','my_priority');""")
```

Instead of:

```
curs.execute("""INSERT INTO todo values('my_item','my_priority');""")
```

You have to write the names of the columns.

You can also create an auto increment column and then you don't need to use the 'i' variable

```
`your_counter` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```